# ¿Por qué no reconoce fontFamily en js?

Tags: javascript, html

Yo estoy varado en un código con **javascript ** el cual consiste en darle a una variable una fuente cursiva y luego dar **display** con un **document.write()**.

```
<script>
let saludos="hola mundo";

saludos.style.fontFamily="cursive";  
document.write(saludos);
</script>
```

Comment: saludos es un humilde string. ¿Por qué supones que le puedes poner estilos como si fuese un elemento del DOM?

Comment: Jjjjj es cierto. No sé que iba a inventar

Answer (score 3):

De hecho te debería estar dando este error:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'fontFamily' of undefined

Pues estás tratando de darle estilos CSS a un elemento que es la variable que no corresponde al DOM, sin contar que no es recomendable usar `document.write` pues esto eliminará el contenido de la web y lo reemplazará por lo que le pases como argumento.

Mejor:

- Declara tu texto en una variable
- Obtén una etiqueta del DOM en una variable
- Asignale a dicha variable por medio de `innerText` el texto de la variable

Es decir, en tu HTML tienes esto

```
<h1 id="titulo"> </h1>
```

En tu JS lo recuperas así

```
let titulo = document.getElementById("titulo");
let texto = " hola mundo ";
```

Y lo asignas así

```
 titulo.innerText = texto;
```

Y ahora sí a la variable título le puedes agregar estilos CSS

Comment: Thank's  you right 

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que tener en cuenta que `document.write` imprime un literal al contenido. Para realizar lo que quieres deberás hacerlo un poco más complejo.

No soy experto pero la solución que yo suelo llevar a cabo cuando necesito hacer esto es lo siguiente:

```js
let saludos="<p id='saludo'>hola mundo</p>";

document.write(saludos);
document.getElementById('saludo').style.color='red';
```

Como puedes comprobar dista un poco de lo que tienes por los siguientes motivos:

- El contenido de tu variable debe contener una etiqueta con id (o class) al que poder asociar el estilo. Si conoces CSS, sabes que los estilos se asignan así y pensarlo de esa manera te facilitará el trabajo también con javascript.
- Primero realiza un `document.write` antes de asignar un estilo.
- Como en la variable tenemos un `<p>` con `id='saludo'`, asignamos el estilo a esa etiqueta.

Answer (score 1):

Estás confundiendo las propiedades `font-family` es para establecer una fuente, `font-style` es para establecer un estilo de fuente, esa es la propiedad que deberías cambiar.

```html
<div style="font-family: 'Courier New'">Esto es un texto de prueba</div>
<div style="font-style: oblique">Esto es un texto de prueba en cursiva</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que no puedes aplicar estilos a una variable pero sí a un elemento html a través de su id.

```js
 function cambiaEstiloFuente() {
          document.getElementById("miParrafo").style.color = "red";
          document.getElementById("miParrafo").style.fontFamily = "mono";
          document.getElementById("miParrafo").style.fontWeight = "bold";
          document.getElementById("miParrafo").style.fontSize = "1.5em";
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <body>

      <p id="miParrafo">Respuesta Ganadora!</p>

      <button type="button" onclick="cambiaEstiloFuente()">Cambia estilo al párrafo</button>
    </body>
  </html>
```